# How to return query CSS elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This code returns parents but ignores the optional selector, how can I return the parent of an element if there is a selector provided.
eg:

```
var paragraph = $("p").parent(".myClass");
```

Should return the parent of a paragraph and that parent has to be of class `myClass`.

```
Some.prototype.parent = function(selector) {
    var parents = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
      parents.push(this.nodes[i].parentElement);
    }
    return parents;
  };
```

Comment: What's wrong with [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)?

Comment: I am implementing a jQuery like framework by my own.

Comment: So add a check to see if the element has that selector....

Comment: But the selector can be whatever, p, div, id etc? How can I do that?

Comment: There is a [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) function on elements...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: `if (this.nodes[i].parentElement.classList.contains(selector)) { // push it  }`

Comment: Surely `parent()` should ignore any query string - the element's parent either has a specific class or nodeType, or it doesn't?

Comment: Keep in mind, if you are implementing your own jQuery look alike, you need to make that very explicit, otherwise future developers stepping into your code base can easily become very confused.

Comment: @Taplar this is only for learning purposes :)